# Even-even-odd rule with multiple terms in the radicand

Tags: radicals

I found [one definition](http://planetmath.org/evenevenoddrule) of the even-even-odd rule by the peeps at planetmath.

They say that *if*

- a real variable to an ***even*** exponent is under a radical
- and the radical has an ***even*** index
- and, when the radical is eliminated, the resulting exponent on the variable is ***odd***

*then* absolute value signs must be placed around the variable.

**My question is how to *apply the rule* when the *radicand* and *result after eliminating the radical* have multiple terms.**

Do you wrap the whole radicand with absolute value signs or how does that work?

Here's the problem that provoked this question:

> Rationalize the expression:
>
> $\sqrt{x^2 + x} - \sqrt{x^2 - x}$

Answer (score 0):

you can multiply $$\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}$$ by $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2+x}}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2+x}}$$

Comment: Thanks, I *did* get that far. What I want to know is, once I multiply by that conjugate, how to go about applying the even-even-odd rule to something with multiple terms.

Answer (score 0):

The exponent in question is the exponent on the whole expression under the radical.  The point is that in $\sqrt{a^2}$ we are guaranteed that $a^2 \ge 0$ so taking the square root makes sense.  As $\sqrt {a^2}$ is defined to be the positive square root, we need an absolute value sign on the $a$.  $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ is incorrect for $a \le 0$.

In your case, if we are just given 
$$\sqrt{(x^2+x)^2}-\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2}$$
we need to put absolute value signs around the expressions because $x^2+x, x^2-x$ might be less than zero, so we get 
$$|x^2+x|-|x^2-x|$$

However if we multiply $$(\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x})(\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2-x})=\sqrt{(x^2+x)^2}-\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2}$$
the original problem tells us that $x^2+x \ge 0, x^2-x \ge 0$ or the original expression does not make sense.  We can use that to avoid the absolute value signs and get $$(x^2+x)-(x^2-x)=2x$$
Note that for $x=\frac 12$, 
$$\sqrt{(x^2+x)^2}-\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2}=\sqrt{(\frac 34)^2}-\sqrt{(\frac {-1}4)^2}=|\frac 34|-|\frac {-1}4|=\frac 12 \neq 2x$$
but here we had nothing to tell us $x^2-x \ge 0$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Maybe it's totally obvious, but could you elaborate on how the original problem "tells us that $x^2+x \ge 0, x^2-x \ge 0$"

Comment: They are both provided to you under the square root sign, so they can't be negative.